# LDAP Authentication against ActiveDirectory

Tags: active-directory, ldap, authentication

I need to create an AD-user who can be used to query ActiveDirectory via LDAP and authenticate users.
Which permissions does this user require?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. Any AD user can query Active Directory.

You can authenticate users by '[binding](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/6a5891b8-928e-4b75-a4a5-0e3b77eaca52)' to the directory using the user's supplied credentials.